# Can't open PDF file from PWA on Android Device

Tags: android, pdf, progressive-web-apps, window.open, window.location

This is just for the record, since I found the solution.

I experienced an Issue happening only on PWA Standalone App on Androïd device.

I used to open PDF file from my standalone VueJs application with this code :

```
window.open('<PDF FILE URL>')
```

or

```
window.open('<PDF FILE URL>', '_blank')
```

In that case, the PDF couldn't be read on Android Device. I had this message

> Impossible d'afficher le PDF/d'ouvrir

I guess that in english error message would be something like :

> Cannot display PDF/Open

Note that in the other side

- It works on standard browser (Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer)
- It works on Apple Device (as PWA)
- it works on Windows App (as PWA)
- I doesn't work on Android as PWA

My solution was to simply change my code with :

```
window.location = '<PDF FILE URL>'
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to simply change my code with :

```
window.location = '<PDF FILE URL>'
```